# How to generate worst case array for heap sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, heapsort

How could i generate the worst case array for Heap Sort for a large array with size of n?

Comment: What have you tried / researched so far? Share your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Heap Sort has O(n* log(n)) time complexities for all the cases ( best case, the average case, and worst case).

Reference: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18391/best-and-worse-case-inputs-for-heap-sort-and-quick-sort